# Linear Independence and Derivative Matrix of the 3rd order polynomial

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, linear-transformations, change-of-basis

I have this question which has two polynomials $$f(t) = t^{3} − 4t^{2} + 3t + 3$$ $$g(t)= t^{3} +2t^{2} +4t -1$$ $$h(t)= 2t^{3} − t^{2} − 3t + 5$$ and I was asked to find whether they are dependent  or not. So what I did was, that I took the standard basis in $\mathbb{P}^{3}[\mathbb{R}] \rightarrow \mathbb{P}^{3}[\mathbb{R}]$ which is $\{1, t, t^{2}, t^{3} \}$. So vector form representation of $f(t)$ and $g(t)$ is $$f = [3,3,-4,1]$$ $$g = [-1, 4, 2, 1]$$ $$h=[5,-3,-1,2]$$
If I write this $af+bg+ch=0 \textrm{ } \forall \textrm{ } a, b, c \textrm{ } \in \textrm{ } \mathbb{R}$, then only possible value for $a, b$ and $c$ is 0, isn't it? So they are indeed independent. The second part was to find the **derivative matrix** in this given basis. The matrix which I calculated is $$\begin{bmatrix} 0&1&0&0\\0&0&2&0\\0&0&0&3\\0&0&0&0\end{bmatrix}$$. I know that this matrix is correct if the basis is $\{1, t, t^{2}, t^{3} \}$. But I am not sure what basis the question is talking about.
[Question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9pPZp.png)

So I am not sure whether I posted the question correctly in mathematical language. If you have any doubt in the way I presented the question, please have look at the image.

Comment: The question that you’ve quoted asks you about the linear dependence of a set of _three_ polynomials, not two as you have here.

Comment: Yeah, right, sorry its my fault, but it doesn't change the approach. I will write $g(t)$ as $g = [-1, 4, 2, 1]$. The result is still the same, they are linearly independent, isn't it?

Comment: what would be the derivative matrix if the basis includes only these 3 polynomials and not the standard basis?

Comment: It’s not possible to represent it relative to that basis alone since even $f'(x)$ doesn’t lie in the span of the three vectors. You need a complete basis for $\mathbb P^3[\mathbb R]$.

Comment: Yeah, I too was thinking of that. I tried to represent $f'(t)$ as a linear combination of the 3 functions $f(t), g(t), h(t)$ but I was getting 4 equations in 3 unknowns. Probably because the component of $t^{3}$ is giving an extra equation. So we would require one more such L.I. polynomial in this basis to make that derivative matrix, isn't it?

Comment: That’s correct.

Comment: Thanks for the help @amd.